# Windows Phone 7: "mailto:" in WebBrowser's html is not firing Navigating event

Tags: windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I have a WebBrowser control which shows some html.

When user clicks some link with "http:...", Navigating event is firing where I am opening IE with requested URL (WebBrowserTask).

I need to open mailing (EmailComposeTask) when the user clicks links with "mailto:..." but Navigating event IS NOT firing with "mailto" links. What to do to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wire up an onclick event to raise the ScriptNotify event [via window.external.Notify] via Javascript.

[image]

[image]

Then WP7 will raise the ScriptNotify event in your C# code.

[image]

Complete Source and Guide: http://www.willasrari.com/blog/external-urls-and-phone-numbers-in-wp7-webbrowser-control/000348.aspx